# Inserting a number in a table(i++), based on a set of equal numbers in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table, and I want an elegant way to start counting from the 1st row and go down all the way, and have all the first equal indexes(12,12,12) inserted as 1 in the column number, the next ones(18,18,18)  inserted as  2, etc

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| Items | Index | Number |
+-------+-------+--------+
| A     | 12    |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| B     | 12    |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| C     | 18    |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| D     | 18    |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| E     | 1800  |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| F     | 1800  |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| G     | x     |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| H     | x     |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
| I     | x     |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

So my final table would be:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| Items | Index | Number |
+-------+-------+--------+
| A     | 12    | 1      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| B     | 12    | 1      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| C     | 18    | 2      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| D     | 18    | 2      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| E     | 1800  | 3      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| F     | 1800  | 3      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| G     | 1900  | 4      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| H     | 1900  | 4      |
+-------+-------+--------+
| I     | 1900  | 4      |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Does the data fit that pattern? Index values clumped together, ascending order?

Comment: Yes...  Correct. They are clumped together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select items, idx, dense_rank() over ( order by idx )
 from table


IT        IDX DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDERBYIDX)
-- ---------- ----------------------------
A          12                            1
B          12                            1
C          18                            2
D          18                            2
E        1800                            3
F        1800                            3
G        1900                            4
H        1900                            4
I        1900                            4
```